# Push notifications in windows8 metro apps?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I have a metro application in which am trying to display notifications whenever my service get updated.I tried to read Metro App push notification concepts overview from microsoft website but I did not get clear idea to implement push-notifications in Metro-apps?

Can anyone give me a sample example to implement push notifications in metro apps using XAML,really it will helpful to me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mentioned documentation, but there is a full sample for notifications: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Push-and-periodic-de225603

Answer (score 1):

You probably have seen the sample below. But just in case...

[Sending push notifications (Metro style apps using JavaScript and HTML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465450.aspx)

[Sending push notifications (Metro style apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868252%28v=win.10%29.aspx)

Comment: @JP Alioto Thank you,Is there any need of Azure server for this implementation?